# Send Mail Asynchronously C#

Tags: c#, email

**Prelude**: I have a SendMail method that sends mail asynchronously e and an Add_Order method that executes some operation and if passed parameters meet some requisites, then the SendMail function is called from it to send a notification to the customer.

**This is the problem**: Once the SendMail is called, the Add_Order() continues to run trying to remove some files that are blocked by another process. At 99% this process is the SendMail() that hasn't finished its job yet.

How can I modify this code in order to resolve this problem? I really appreciate it if someone can help me.
Thank you in advice

```
[HttpPost, Route("order_insert")]
    public HttpResponseMessage wsAdd_Order(wsOrdineTulero nOrdine)
    {
        ...

        sendMail(isProd ? rCustomer["MailingList"].ToString() : "f.mail@mail.it", "", ccn, (isProd ? "" : "[TEST] ") + "Tulero - Conferma di spedizione", string.Format(templateMail, mail), true, allegati);

        // This Foreach throw the error because these files are alredy taken by SendMail process 
        foreach (string s in allegati) { File.Delete(s); }
    }




private bool sendMail(string dest, string cc, string ccn, string oggetto, string testo, bool isHtml, string[] allegati)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("", 25);

             ...   

            smtpClient.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                string sQuery = helper.GetQuery("ADD_MAIL", new string[7] { mail.From.Address, dest, cc, ccn, oggetto, testo.Replace("'", "''"), allegati == null ? "" : string.Join("|", allegati) });
                try { helper.ExecuteSQLNonQuery(sQuery); }
                catch (Exception ex) { helper.NotifyLog(Severity.EXCEPTION_TRACE, ex, "Errore durante la registrazione della mail. Query:|" + sQuery); }
                smtpClient.Dispose();
                mail.Dispose();
            };
            smtpClient.SendAsync(mail, null);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { helper.NotifyLog(Severity.FATAL, ex, string.Format("Failed to send mail|dest: {0}|cc: {1}|ccn: {2}|oggetto: {3}|testo: {4}|isHtml: {5}|allegati: {6}", dest, cc, ccn, oggetto, testo, isHtml, allegati != null ? string.Join("|\\t", allegati) : "")); }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: await `smtpClient.SendAsync`, make sendMail async and await that one too.

Comment: `SendAsync` predates async and await and works by event, use `SendMailAsync` , which returns a task, and await that.

Comment: also, should you really delete the files if sendMail fails?

Comment: @Steve I need to delete the files (bill of lading) after the mail is sent, otherwise files are sent everytime to the ERP

Comment: @TheGeneral can you please modify my code with your suggestion? I would be really grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the async await pattern.
Some methods are executed asynchronously as youve said yourself.

You can block execution of code by using the `await` keyword in front of the asynchronous call. However, in order for you to use the `await` keyword, you need to mark the method that calls it `async`, as it now executes something asynchronousy, meaning it is itself async.

This should do it:

```
[HttpPost, Route("order_insert")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> wsAdd_Order(wsOrdineTulero nOrdine)
{
    var success = await sendMail(isProd ? rCustomer["MailingList"].ToString() : "f.mail@mail.it", "", ccn, (isProd ? "" : "[TEST] ") + "Tulero - Conferma di spedizione", string.Format(templateMail, mail), true, allegati);

    // This Foreach throw the error because these files are alredy taken by SendMail process 
    if (success) {
        foreach (string s in allegati) { File.Delete(s); }
    }
}

private async Task<bool> sendMail(string dest, string cc, string ccn, string oggetto, string testo, bool isHtml, string[] allegati)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("", 25);

        smtpClient.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            string sQuery = helper.GetQuery("ADD_MAIL", new string[7] { mail.From.Address, dest, cc, ccn, oggetto, testo.Replace("'", "''"), allegati == null ? "" : string.Join("|", allegati) });
            try { helper.ExecuteSQLNonQuery(sQuery); }
            catch (Exception ex) { helper.NotifyLog(Severity.EXCEPTION_TRACE, ex, "Errore durante la registrazione della mail. Query:|" + sQuery); }
            smtpClient.Dispose();
            mail.Dispose();
        };
        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { helper.NotifyLog(Severity.FATAL, ex, string.Format("Failed to send mail|dest: {0}|cc: {1}|ccn: {2}|oggetto: {3}|testo: {4}|isHtml: {5}|allegati: {6}", dest, cc, ccn, oggetto, testo, isHtml, allegati != null ? string.Join("|\\t", allegati) : "")); }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would add also the code to show how to call it considering the fact that, in case of error, no file should be deleted- And use SendMailAsync instead of SendAsync

Comment: You're right, I've made the changes that you suggest

Comment: It seems the working way to do it, thank you both of you

Comment: I tried to suggest and edit to your solution, but the queue is alredy full. Please change `await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail, null);` in  `await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail);` because the SendMailAsync() method only accept one parameter that is the mail object

Comment: @FedericoMTM I have done what you suggested. Thanks for spotting it.